# Strongloop model discovery through arc not creating basic object methods like find(), findAll() etc

Tags: strongloop

I have created a db object through database discovery through arc. My database is an already existing MySQL database for which I have created objects through arc GUI. When I try to query the model through `find()` method it gives me an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined
```

Please tell me where I am making a mistake or the correct method to query the model.

Comment: It looks like the object you are using is not defined.

Comment: Where do I need to define it? I have attached it to the db in my server/models-config.json and also the objects are there in the common/models/ directory. I am not able to figure out what is happening.

Comment: Can you show your code how and where do you call find method?

Comment: var loopback = require('loopback');
`code` var app = loopback();
app.model('users', {dataSource: 'new_crownit'});
var Users = app.models.users;
var result = Users.find({where: {name: 'John'}, limit: 3}, function(err, accounts) {/* Some code here*/ }); `code`

Comment: Post brief code of what you've done so far.